# Object colour gradient not working

Tags: rendering

So basically I've been following a tutorial on youtube, and one of the steps is to use to 'color ramp' (below) to make a gradient on the object. My problem is that when rendered, or in the rendered preview, the object turns entirely yellow. I'll enclose some pictures below.[image: this is frame 25, everything is as it should be]

As far as I'm aware, there are no keyframes which make the object turn yellow, though I'm not entirely sure.

The object turns yellow in the following frames: 1-2, 4-12, 26-35, 38-113

Edit: When I change the colour type from RGB to HSV or HSL, the gradient appears. Also, when I move all the colour stops to the left side of the slider, the gradient appears, though only on the very right side of the shape, and it's way to sudden for my liking. It seems that it renders the first colour quite heavily, and then doesn't do anything else.It also may be affected by the elevation of the object. It appears as though if it is any lower or any higher than a particular level, it will turn yellow. Either that or that only on particular parts of the curve it's following, will it have the gradient. Another thing I found is that if the object is rendered in Edit Mode, then the gradient works just fine. It is only Object Mode that it stuffs up.

[image: As you can see here, the render preview is entirely yellow, while the gradient above is set to a gradient][image: this is frame 26, everything has turned yellow for some reason]

Any help is appreciated :)
[image]

Comment: do you have an hdri in the scene

Comment: no i don't.  I just went to world properties and set the background to black from there

Comment: Instead of playing a guess game, please edit your question and add a link to your file, so that others can help you better.

Comment: Best way to link the project?

Comment: See this to know how to upload a .blend file along with your question - https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Comment: Hello :). This seems to be caused by the Bevel modifier. When you disable it, it works just fine. No idea why though.

Comment: Yeah. I've been playing around with it since, and found the same thing. Just weird that it does so.

Comment: just move the bevel modifier at the top, just figured it out

Comment: THANKYOU  SO MUCH..... you are the BEST!

Answer (score 0):

Go to overlays tab
[image]

There you will find the [face orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html) option.
[image]

Enable it

If the object turn blue its ok.

But if it is red then go to `EDIT MODE`, Select all<kbd>A</kbd>, and then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> to `recalculate normals`

See if that makes a difference.

Comment: The object blue btw.

Comment: Have you tried putting the colour node into the fac.

Comment: yes i have, that is the way it should have been anyway... oopsy i was messing around with it hoping something would work